# Word placement in join banner is awkward

Tags: discussion, grammatical-correction

Banner when not logged in states:

> Join them; it only takes a minute.

The effort does not only take. Instead, the effort takes only a minute. Hence, banner should read:

> Join them; it takes only a minute.

Different placements convey different meanings, as is the case in these three sentences:
Only John likes Mary.
John only likes Mary.
John likes only Mary.

Comment: I highly doubt this is a real grammatical error. I wonder what the [english.se] community would say about it. As far as I know, the current construction of the sentence is valid.

Comment: Are you a native English speaker? As one, I see absolutely no difference between the two.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The English Language & Usage community has the same "Join them; it only takes a minute." on their homepage, so I think they're okay with it.

Comment: @Davy M: I think that's just because every site uses the same call-to-action template, but I'd roll with that :P

Answer (score 7):

> Different placements convey different meanings, as is the case in these three sentences:
>   Only John likes Mary.
>   John only likes Mary.
>   John likes only Mary.

Yes, but that's a different set of sentences. "It only takes a minute" is idiomatic and there is practically zero ambiguity as to what it means. No one thinks that joining the site does *nothing but* take a minute; it is obvious in context what other effect it has — namely, the creation of an account.

In fact, a similar argument could be made about the latter two sentences in your example: unless John is described as a primitive life form that doesn't know how to do anything except have an affection for a specific human being, you'd be hard-pressed to find any meaningful difference between the two.

Also on English Language & Usage: [Correct position of “only”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only)

Answer (score 0):

> Join them; it only takes a minute.

In this sentence, "it" refers to the gerund form of "Join them", so it could be re-written as:

> Joining them only takes a minute.

Now it's obvious that "only" is an adverb to the gerund "Joining," and "takes a minute" is the verb clause that the gerund is doing, finally meaning: The action of joining only takes a minute to accomplish. So the "only" is in the right place. If it were located after "takes," then it would apply to "takes" and not to "Joining." Therefore:

> Join them; it only takes a minute.

Is perfect grammar.

Answer (score -1):

So let's break this down

> Join them; It only takes a minute

We could always phrase it better as

> It only takes a minute to join them

but I think they're trying to emphasize the `Join them` part, first.

`only` is used as an adverb (in reference to the verb `takes`), and it's quite acceptable to be where it is (there's no other verbs to make it ambiguous). By placing it earlier, it emphasizes the word. So it's not awkward usage at all. Placing it later, as you've suggested, would remove the emphasis on `only`

Comment: Just me but I don't think its emphasis is affected at all - "it takes only a minute" has the same ring to it to my ears as "it only takes a minute".

Comment: Actually, to my ears the ring is quite different; "It only takes a minute" has a much more conclusive and uplifting rythm, whereas "It takes only a minute" is a hassle to say.